# Is there are any universal methods or software for reaction rate modelling?

Tags: kinetics, software

In software like DWSIM are used databanks which contains enthalpy and entropy at 298 K and more other information about chemicals. This software can create a steady-state system, where showed state of matter, temperature of reaction, etc.

But I can't find any software for calculation of reaction rate. I know, that chemical kinetics is using experimentally measured time of reaction and concentration of matter. So what should we do, if we want to know an estimated time of reaction?

Comment: Like Aspen etc? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_process_simulators

Comment: @Mithoron, Aspren looks like software for thermodynamical modelling. Or may be you did mean that there is available to find time of reaction? I watched tutorial on Aspren. Looks like it's same as DWSIM.

Comment: @Mithoron, yes! Aspren is one which supports kinetic calculations. Thanks.
Yeah, and may be you know any freeware alternatives to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern process simulators, including DWSIM, feature reactor models which can calculate and display reaction rates. For PFR and CSTR models you must also consider the reactor volume to estimate the reaction time.